# How to interpret PCA plots made using R

Tags: r, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I'm using PCA for the first time and just experimenting with it. I used PCA on my dataset that can be found [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/i2o6ywbdu2ws55k/wine_nocolor.csv)

```
wine <- read.csv("wine_nocolor.csv")
wine1 <- wine[2:13]
pca <- princomp(wine1[1:11], cor=TRUE)
biplot(pca)
```

produces this plot[image]

**Questions**

- How would I interpret the above graph?
- My aim is to apply dimension reduction to see which attributes can be taken out while not losing meaning of the data. How can I do this with PCA?

Comment: My guess is that this plot is the projected data in 2D where the green arrows are also *projected* directions of maximum variance found by PCA.

Comment: This question should be closed: there is many similar questions already on the site. Search `PCA biplot` and read half a dozen top relevant items.

Comment: -1. This question shows zero research effort.

Comment: @amoeba does the duplicate also show no effort? I've tried to generate the plots for my dataset, I just need some help in making sense of them.

Comment: The duplicate sounds more reasonable :) I have just left a comment there. There was indeed some overlap between these two questions, it is usually better to avoid that. E.g. ask one specific question, wait until it (hopefully) gets clarified, then with your increased understanding write a follow-up question, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I just didn't want it to seem like I'm not doing any effort from my end. I'm finding all this information very exciting but just lack the statistical background required to make sense of it all.